# List in a Loop and Subprocesses, Standard Output

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7

I want to call a subprocess in a for loop and put the vertical lines horizontally in a list for printing them by separating by comma.
My code is like this ;

```
import serial
import time
import subprocess                                                               #test
subprocess.call(['echo','I am Learning to use Subprocesses'])   #when Using subprocess.call([*1,*2])   *1 is the first argument and it is the bash code, *2 is the opti$
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 4800, timeout = 1)
file = open("/home/pi/GPSWIFIMODIFIED.csv", "a")
file.write('\n')

for i in range(0,50):
       date = time.time()
       val = ser.readline();
       if val.find("GPGGA")==-1: continue
####      subprocess.call([iwlist, scan and the stuff
###       iwlout = sys.stdout(((( output on the screen)))))) the output which iwlist wlan0 scan will put on the screen
###       line = iwlout.readline()
###       for j in range (1,40):
###             if line.find("Cell +j")==-1:
####                    mylistofwifi = [line.find("Address"),line.find("Quality"),line.find("IEEE"),line.find("Pairwise")]


####    ########################### ######Here there must be iwlist scan, and the gathering must be done

       print >> file ,date,',',val[:42],',','WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE'#     print mylistofwifi will be here
file.close()
```

The lines which works at the moment stores the data line by line and what I want is to add the lines that I choose from iwlist scan outputs to the end of the lines that has time and the GPGGA data.

The problem is that I am new to Python and I am not able to use lists or parsing or the subprocesses efficiently.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**The output from `sudo wlan0 iwlist` scan  :**

```
 Cell 01 - Address: 00:26:99:4D:0F:34
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=18/100  Signal level=18/100
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"STAFF"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000db0b79259
                    Extra: Last beacon: 0ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00055354414646
                    IE: Unknown: 010882040B0C12161824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706494520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0504000E8D5B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (2) : 802.1x Proprietary
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 851E06008F000F00FF03590045452D472D303100000000000000000004000027
                    IE: Unknown: 9606004096000E00
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040961401
          Cell 02 - Address: 00:26:99:4D:0D:35
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=21/100  Signal level=21/100
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"eduroam"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001021e097bd4
                    Extra: Last beacon: 0ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007656475726F616D
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706494520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0503000C8D5B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (2) : 802.1x Proprietary
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 851E02008F000F00FF03590045452D472D303200000000000000000003000027
                    IE: Unknown: 9606004096000B00
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (2) : 802.1x Proprietary
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040961401
          Cell 03 - Address: 00:26:99:4D:0D:30
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=21/100  Signal level=21/100
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"CONF"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001021e0e36dd
                    Extra: Last beacon: 0ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0004434F4E46
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 0706494520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0503000C8D5B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 851E02008F000F00FF03590045452D472D303200000000000000000003000027
                    IE: Unknown: 9606004096000B00
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
                    IE: Unknown: DD050040961400
```

**The output of running the file without the `subprocess.call([iwlist and the stuff` (not including the commented lines)**

```
1407868084.56 , $GPGGA,104023.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868085.21 , $GPGGA,104024.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868086.21 , $GPGGA,104025.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868087.62 , $GPGGA,104026.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868088.25 , $GPGGA,104027.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868089.21 , $GPGGA,104028.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868090.21 , $GPGGA,104029.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868091.2 , $GPGGA,104030.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
1407868092.61 , $GPGGA,104031.000,5323.0922,N,00636.1480,W , WIFI DATA WILL BE HERE
```

Comment: Do you want ALL the lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get the output of a process:

```
from subprocess import check_output
iwout = check_output(['wlan0', 'iwlist', 'scan']).splitlines()
```

And then when you print:

```
print >> file, date, ',', val[:42], ',', ', '.join(iwout)
```

You can replace `iwout` with `map(strip, iwout)` to remove the unnecessary whitespaces.

As you can see I removed the `sudo`, because it could block the execution asking for the password, you shouldn't include a `sudo` call in your script unless they are interactive, otherwise you should run all the command with root privileges, and then perform all the invocations without `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to use sudo, otherwise I can't see all the Cells , I just can see the cell which I am connected----- But the problem is I just want specific lines from the "sudo wlan0 iwlist scan" output, the lines which contains ESSID, Quality, Encryption, 802.11 for first cell, same for the second cell, same for the third cell, until the last cell, can a selector code added into check_output, or can it be redirected?